# SSL DB2 connection failed

Tags: java, ssl, db2, ibm-cloud

I am trying to connect to a DB2 database using SSL on IBM Bluemix.

When I first tried to connect without SSL, it doesn't work. After reading the documentation, I have realized that it connects to the database with SSL enabled.

I tried using the following code to get it connect to the database:

```
public boolean connect() {
  try {
    String url = "jdbc:db2://" + serverName + ":" + port + "/" + dbName+
                 ":securityMechanism=9";    

    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, passWord);
    st = connection.createStatement();
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
  }

  return false;
}
```

Still I am not too sure on how to use the SSL certificate provided with the code above.

I tried searching for examples but most of the explanations are either unclear or used for another database system.

Comment: What is the error message you see? Are you using the Liberty buildpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Liberty, a datasource is generated for you, and you can look it up using jndi.

```
@Resource(lookup = "jdbc/mydb")
private DataSource myDataSource;
Connection c = myDataSource.getConnection();
```

"mydb" is the name of the SQLDB service

https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/02/07/java-db2-10-minutes/

Answer (score 1):

According to the SQLDB [documentation](http://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/#services/SQLDB/index.html#SQLDB#d68e1115), If you use the latest *com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver* with the JDBC connection, the current SSL certificate is bundled with the driver and does not need manually installing.

The following snippet shows you how to use the connection details available from VCAP_SERVICES to connect to SQLDB over SSL.

```
public class SSLTEST { 
/**
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) { 
        String ServerName = "hostname or IP address";
        int PortNumber = 50001;
        String DatabaseName = "SQLDB";
        String user = "your_user_id_from_VCAP_SERVICES";
        String userPassword = "your_password_from_VCAP_SERVICES";
```

`java.util.Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();

    properties.put("user", "user ID that has access to SQLDB");
    properties.put("password", "password for the user ID that has access to SQLDB");
    properties.put("sslConnection", "true");

    String url = "jdbc:db2://" + ServerName + ":"+ PortNumber + "/" +
    DatabaseName + ":" + traceFileLocation + ";";

    java.sql.Connection con = null; 
    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance(); 
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: failed to load Db2 jcc driver."); 
    }

    try
    {
        System.out.println("url: " + url);
        con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(url, properties);
        if (con != null) {
            System.out.println("Success");
        } else { 
            System.out.println("Failed to make the connection");
        }
        con.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        if (con != null) {
            try {
                con.close(); 
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace(); 
            }
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

finally i use datasource to connect to the database.
Context ic = new InitialContext();
DataSource db = (DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/MyDatabase");